# SFTP isn't working anymore

Tags: debian, ssh, networking, sftp

Today I connected to sftp and it worked, but a few minutes later I got disconnected and couldn't connect again. Restarting sshd did nothing, so I rebooted the server and sftp started working again for just a few minutes.

Here's the last part of the log when I try to connect:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ns1 ([xx.xx.xx.xx]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:8: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys:8: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug2: channel 0: request subsystem confirm 1
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
packet_write_wait: Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Broken pipe
```

I'm using openssh on Debian 10.9, everything is updated.

Thanks!

Comment: When sftp stops working can you still ssh to that server?

Comment: Yes, I can. SSH has always been working.

Comment: If you `ssh {server} man sh | wc` does it complete? If not, it's almost certainly an MTU networking issue

Comment: It doesn't complete. I started thinking it may be a networking issue, but the Hetzner support won't listen to me unfortunately.

Comment: On the server, if you can, reduce the MTU down by 100 at a time until it starts working again. Then you can increase by "a little at a time" until it's just under the point where it breaks. Use `ip link | grep -i --color=always mtu` and `ip link set {device} mtu 1400`

Comment: I lowered it to as low as 500 and it still doesn't work. In the meantime I booted from a live distro and it works there no matter the MTU.

Comment: What did you do via stfp just before you could no longer connect to it?

Comment: I was editing some files through vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found the problem. The server's bandwidth was 100% used. When I managed to reduce the bandwidth usage just a bit, it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I installed a package named, I believe `rng-tools5` ([debian package page](https://packages.debian.org/buster/rng-tools5)), and since then no issue with the lack of entropy, which was my type of issue (a reboot may be needed). I did it mainly on the server, which was making problems, but also on my clients.

Excerpt:

> The `rngd` daemon acts as a bridge between a Hardware TRNG (true random number generator) such as the ones in some Intel/AMD/VIA chipsets, and the kernel's PRNG (pseudo-random number generator).

---

You can then just see what it is able to utilize with:

```
sudo rngd -v
```

example output:

```
Available entropy sources:
    Intel/AMD hardware rng
    DRNG
```